# Diagnose AWS RDS Usage

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm fairly new to network and database management, and have an SQL instance on Amazon Web Services.  AWS shows free storage with only 1.5 GB left and memory almost maxed out as well, but SQL says the database_size is only 1.5 GB after using sp_spaceused.  I thought it was mainly the transaction log, which should be included in the AWS automated backups, and shrinkfile helped free a little bit of storage, but is there a view like Windows Explorer that shows all of the files and items on the AWS/EC2 instance that's taking up so much space?  Thanks in advance!

EDIT:  the system databases don't appear to be taking up much space, either:

```
name    DataFileSizeMB  LogFileSizeMB
master      4.000000    0.750000
tempdb      2.000000    0.500000
model       3.062500    0.750000
msdb        137.750000  74.937500
dbadmin     38.062500   26.562500
testdb      1475.062500 1.062500
umanager    3.062500    0.765625
```

The storage and memory are slowly being freed up as time passes, as well.  Is there any way to see: what's on the virtual server; how much space everything on the server is using; how to delete large files on the server?

Comment: Could it be slow query logs? Try checking the size of the system database in addition to your application's database.

Comment: I think it might be.  I'm trying to do a trace, but what's the difference between system database and application database?  The disk space report in SQL says 92% unused Data Files Space Usage and 60% unused Transaction Log Space Usage.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178028.aspx

Comment: Thanks Mark B.  The size of each data file size and log file size seems insignificant: 
name       DataMB   LogMB
master 4.000000 0.750000
tempdb 2.000000 0.500000
model 3.062500 0.750000
msdb 137.750000 74.937500
admin 38.062500 26.562500
DB1475.062500 1.062500
UManager 3.062500 0.765625